# My app crashes in retrieving first five rows videos path in sqllite and works fine for rest

Tags: android, sqlite

My app crashes in retrieving first five rows path in sqllite but works fine for rest i.e.it crashes if value of 'a' is from 1 to 5.I am posting that part of code that deals with retrieving videos from sqllite.

MainActvity.java

```
          sql helper = new sql(this);
    private Cursor getEvents() {  //data fetch from database
                sql mDbHelper = new sql(getApplicationContext());
                SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                Cursor cursor = db.query(sql.databasename, null, null, null, null,
                    null, null);


                return cursor;
          }
        private void checkEvents(Cursor cursor) {
                cursor.moveToPosition((int) (a-1));
                b = cursor.getString(0);
                cursor.moveToPosition((int) (a-2));
                c = cursor.getString(0);
                cursor.moveToPosition((int) (a-3));
                d = cursor.getString(0);
                cursor.moveToPosition((int) (a-4));
                e = cursor.getString(0);
                cursor.moveToPosition((int) (a-5));
                f = cursor.getString(0);




      }
public void retrieveVid()
{
    Cursor cursor = getEvents();
    checkEvents(cursor);

}

    public void insertVid()              //Storing video to SQLLite
    { 


        try{
            if(countClick%5==1)
        a=helper.insert(fileUri);
            else if(countClick%5==2)
        a=helper.insert(fileUri1);
            else if(countClick%5==3)
        a=helper.insert(fileUri2);
            else if(countClick%5==4)
        a=helper.insert(fileUri3);
            else if(countClick%5==0)
        a=helper.insert(fileUri4);


        if(a>=0){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Record Successfully Saved to SQLLITE row="+a,30).show();

        }

        else{

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),  "Not Saved", 30).show();

        }}
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "there is error",5).show();
        }

    }
```

sql.java

```
package com.example.Assignment;


import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;


public class sql extends SQLiteOpenHelper{



final static String databasename="videodb";
final static int databaseversion=2;

public sql(Context ctx){
super(ctx,databasename,null,databaseversion);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
try{

Log.d("tag4545","database");   
db.execSQL("create table videodb (vid VARCHAR)");

}
catch(SQLException e){e.printStackTrace();
}

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("drop table if Exists videodb");

    onCreate(db);


}

public long insert(Uri fileUri ) {

SQLiteDatabase base=getWritableDatabase();


ContentValues value=new ContentValues();
value.put("vid",fileUri.getPath());



long a= base.insert("videodb", null, value);  //returns the row ID of the newly inserted row, or -1 if an error occurred

return a; 
}


}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of those `moveToPosition` calls in `checkEvents`?

Comment: @CL to move to last five rows..'a' stores the row id of last row in which video is stored..suppose i have stored 10 videos then it will show last 5 videos but if i have stored less than  5 videos in sqllite then the app crashes in retrieving them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have one video (ie `a = 1`) then what would you expect the behaviour of this line to be:

```
cursor.moveToPosition((int) (a-5));
```

I don't think a cursor will like a negative index!  You should check that the index you are attempting to retrieve is greater than zero before using it.

Comment: thanks..then i should use if loop to check whether value of 'a' is 1,2,3,4 or greater then 5

Comment: Or just check the return value of `moveToPosition`.